# SQL Server 2014 SP1 on Windows 10 - service doesn't start automatically

Tags: sql-server

I've upgraded Win 7 to Win 10 with SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express x64 on it and the SQL Server service doesn't start automatically after machine restarts, even though it is configured to start so and it had before the upgrade.

Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Maybe try serverfault or dba.

Comment: Have you checked the error event logs?  Sometimes it will try to start and fail.